# Is TeX the only document creator with syntax highlighting?

Tags: listings, highlighting

Is there any other document creator software other than TeX (word processor, DTP, webapp etc.) that can include syntax highlighted source code in a number of programming languages?

For me it seems like a very unique feature to TeX, that without using an external tool (formatter website+copypaste, IDE+copypaste, separate executable, commercial plugin) you can include syntax-highlighted source code.

I'm specifically asking for software with the primary purpose of creating written documents (articles, books etc.), but with the ability to include syntax highlighted source code snippets. I'm aware of the following solutions:

- LaTeX + `listings` or similar package
- LaTeX + `pygments` python library + `texments`/`verbments`/`minted`/`pygmentex` package
- Word processor + copypaste from an IDE/editor
- Word processor + copypaste from a website such as http://www.tohtml.com
- Word processor + some kind of plugin

From this list only the first option is completely implemented in LaTeX, while the others use at least 2 programs, one for the document editing and another for the highlighting. What I want to verify is the suspicion that LaTeX is the only way to create a document with code snippets without invoking external programs.

Comment: What is the workflow for the doc creation? Most editors notepad++ etc. has code highlighting capabilities and you can print it as is with PDF printer(I guess). But that doesn't feel like what you are asking.

Comment: [`pygments`](http://pygments.org/) is a generic syntax highlighter which supports a lot of languages; `minted` uses it under the hood. `:)`

Comment: And, of course, [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) — which uses LaTeX for PDFs but can also create other formats like HTML with syntax highlighting.

Comment: start using VI. See http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/unix-as-ide-editing/ for how to use VI as an IDE.

Comment: Speaking of vim, Aditya is the author of a highlighter module in ConTeXt which uses vim under the hood as well. `:)`

Comment: I've tried to clarify the question.

Comment: Docbook is capable of syntax highlighting. You can read more [here](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/SyntaxHighlighting.html). By its nature, docbook requires external tools to work, which is why I'm mentioning this in a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: It is not clear to me how this is a TeX question. Since I use LaTeX I ahve never tried [coooder](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/coooder) for LibreOffice, but the description suggests it might do what you are asking (but probably not as good as LaTeX).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is explicitly asking for a program that is NOT TeX.

Comment: Why are ruling out "Word processor + some kind of plugin" isn't listings just "some kind of plugin"?

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Yes, this may be off-topic, I've tried to make it more TeX-specific by that last sentence "Is LaTeX really the only way to ...".  I'm interested in whether LaTeX is truly unique in this respect. Yes, listings may be considered a LaTeX plugin. There is a very fine line here; I would consider a Word plugin written in VBA to be native to Word, while a COM application written in e.g. C# a separate executable.